# Cannot Resolve Symbol setOnClickListener & ";" & ")" expected

Tags: java, android

I am receiving the following error

> `Cannot Resolve Symbol setOnClickListener`

on the Java code below. I am also receiving an error on

> `public void onClick(View v) {`

between `k` & `(` there is a `;` expected and between `w` and `v` there is a `) & ;` expected. I'm not entirely sure how I am receiving these errors, any help will be appreciated.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    //Creating button references for the buttons corresponding to their IDs through findViewById
    Button rB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rButton);
    Button lB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.lButton);
    //Register click event with first button
    rB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TextView txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);//Correspond the text view to its ID
            txtView.setTextSize(14); //Change text size
        }
    });
    //Register click event with second button
    lB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TextView txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView); //Correspond the text view to its ID
            txtView.setTextSize(24); //Change text size
        }
    });


}
```

Below is my xml code;

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView android:text="Please Type Here" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:inputType="text"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#FF0000FF"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/view" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="LEFT"
        android:id="@+id/lButton"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/view"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RIGHT"
        android:id="@+id/rButton"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/view"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Just from the error message, there is a typo somewhere... Probably not in the code you provided though.

Comment: Where exactly is this code? In a method such as `onCreate()` or in the class body?

Comment: @laalto My apologies, I forgot the rest of my Java code, it is inside the `public class MainActivity`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put your code in a method body such as `onCreate()`. It's not syntactically valid to have it in the class body.

Move the code that calls `setOnClickListener()` to `onCreate()` after `setContentView()`. You can have the variable declarations in the class level (but initialize them with `findViewById()` only after `setContentView()`.)

Comment: Thanks, that helps me understand what I was doing incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Move the following code:

```
//Creating button references for the buttons corresponding to their IDs through findViewById
    Button rB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rButton);
    Button lB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.lButton);
    //Register click event with first button
    rB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TextView txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);//Correspond the text view to its ID
            txtView.setTextSize(14); //Change text size
        }
    });
    //Register click event with second button
    lB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TextView txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView); //Correspond the text view to its ID
            txtView.setTextSize(24); //Change text size
        }
    });
```

inside the onCreate method, the reason is because those statements must be inside a method, not any method, but one where the views are valid, (like the onCreate)